# efficient regex for key/value matches

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string that represents a list of unique key/value pairs like so:

```
a:1;b:2;c:3;d:4
```

Checking whether the string contains a specific key/value pair is straight forward.  But let's say I want to take advantage of the fact that the keys are unique.  Is there a way to optimize the regex so that if it finds a key with a value different than the one I want, it immediately fails rather than continue scanning to the end of the string?

So, in the example above, if I want to see if `b:3` is in the string, I'd want the match to fail as soon as it finds b:2.  (note: an inverse search for something like `b:[^3]` isn't going to work for cases where they key `b` is missing)

Comment: This won't reduce complexity though, assuming position are random, the complexity are going to be the same.

Comment: Use a lookahead assertion `^(?!.*b:[^3]).*b:3`

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest will be to use a two step approch. Idon't know what programming language, you're using (so this is pseudicode), but use this regex:

```
b:(\d)
```

This will find the first `'b:`' in the string and save the `value` as `Group 1`. Now check if the value in `Group 1` is the one, you want.

For instance in JavaScript you could do:

```
var text = 'a:1;b:2;c:3;d:4';
var match = text.match(/b:(\d)/);
if (match[1] === '3')
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

This will be a very fast approach.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/t4Ewu3/1)

`^[^b]*b:3`

Explanation:
Asserting that the match starts at the begging of the line with `^` guarantees that a line will contain exactly one match.
using `[^b]*` expands the match to the first occurrence of 'b' and terminates the expansion, as it's not allowed to move past there.
finally, the evaluation of `b:3` occurs which either validate or invalidate the match, with no chance of re-evaluation or backtracking as the only quantifier is terminated

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
import re 

for dic in [{"a":1},{"b":2}]:   
    for  k,v in dic.items():
        regex = r".+?;%s:[^%d]" %(k,v)
        if re.match(regex, test): break
```